# Data Types and Structs

Tags: c++, struct, types

I'm reviewing for a test, and I am stumped by this question.

Consider the following declarations:

```
enum CategoryType {HUMANITIES, SOCIALSCIENCE, NATURALSCIENCE}; 
const int NUMCOURSES = 100; 
struct CourseRec 
{ 
         string courseName; 
         int courseNum; 
         CategoryType courseCategory; 
}; 
typedef CourseRec CourseList [NUMCOURSES]; 
CourseList courses; 
int index1, index2;
```

52. What is the data type of the expression courses[index1] .courseName[index2] ?

(a) CourseList 
(b) CourseRec 
(c) string 
(d) char 
(e) none; the expression is syntactically invalid

I thought that the answer would be string, since courseName is a string, or maybe even CourseRec, since it is in the struct, but the answer is (d)char. Why is this a char data type? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: should it be typdef CourseRec[NUMCOURSES] CourseList ?

Comment: No, C++ isn't that straight-forward.

Comment: Nope. The order in a typedef is just like in the definition of the object. It would be different for #define.

Comment: The answer isn't `char` though, it's `const char&`

Comment: So lets make it *"(f) the question is invalid"*?

Comment: Since this is test review, I added the "homework" tag.

Comment: Oh you're right.  I had a brain fart.  Sorry about that.

Comment: CourseList is non-const, so wouldn't the type be `char&`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's go step by step:

courses[index1] .courseName[index2]

- courses is array of `CourseRec`
- courses[index1] is `CourseRec`
- courses[index1] .courseName is `string`
- courses[index1] .courseName[index2] is `char` *

* - actually it is `char&`

Comment: If `string` is `std::string` its actually `const char&`.

Comment: This is how a programmer thinks when they are facing some crazy construct. +1

Comment: Ahem, it would actually be `char&` as noted by Mark B as `courseName` is not const.

Answer (score 0):

A string is an array of char, so taking anyString[0] returns the char in the first position of the string array.

Comment: A C++ string is *not* simply an array of char, but you are correct in that the `[]` operator on a C++ string does return a char corresponding to the specified position in the string.

Comment: It actually returns a reference to the char, not the char by-value.